# WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated is not working

Tags: asp.net

This my second post on this issue> I have been reading for days on this issue...  any suggestion why

```
LoginOk = WebSecurity.Login(email, password, rememberMe)  **Is true but**
WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated, WebSecurity.CurrentUserName and the other items do not get set on the LoggedIn Page. 

// Attempt to log in using provided credentials
if (WebSecurity.Login(email, password, rememberMe)) {

    // Added this code for testing... 
    LoginOk = WebSecurity.Login(email, password, rememberMe);

    if (LoginOk)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Account/LoggedIn");

        return;
    } 

  Context.RedirectLocal(returnUrl);                
  return;
} else {
    ModelState.AddFormError("The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
}
```

**The code for /Account/LoggedIn page**

```
     <p>Lake LoggedIn page </p>
     <p>WebSecurity.CurrentUserName should be here -> <strong>@WebSecurity.CurrentUserName</strong> <-! </p>
     <p> WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated should be here -> <strong> @WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated  </strong><-!</p>
     <p> WebSecurity.CurrentUserId should be here -> <strong> @WebSecurity.CurrentUserId </strong><-!</p>
     <p> Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated should be here -> <strong> @Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated </strong><-!</p>



        @if (!userName.IsEmpty()) {
            <p> WebSecurity.IsConfirmed(userName) should be here -> <strong> @WebSecurity.IsConfirmed(userName) </strong><-!</p>
                         }else{  
        <p> WebSecurity.IsConfirmed(userName) should be here ->   <-!</p>    
                          }



                         <a href="~/Account/Logout" title="Logout">Logout</a>



           </div>
```

**This the result of the LoggedIn code above**

WebSecurity.CurrentUserName should be here -> <-!

WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated should be here -> False <-!

WebSecurity.CurrentUserId should be here -> -1 <-!

Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated should be here -> False <-!

WebSecurity.IsConfirmed(userName) should be here -> <-!
Logout